# Best Practice for passing arguments in a class Python

Tags: python, class, oop, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm new to OOP and pretty sure the way I'm about to solve something is not the smartest.

I'm building a custom K-means Algorithm and want to give options for different distance functions.

The way I am about to solve it, is building if statements and calculate the distances respectively.

For Example:

```
class ExampleDist():
    def __init__(self, measure="euklid"):
        self.measure = measure
    
    def euklid_distance(x_1,x_2):
        dist = np.linalg.norm(x_1-x_2)
        return dist
    
    def abs_distance(x_1,x_2):
        dist = np.absolute(x_1-x_2)
        return dist
    
    def dist(self, x_1, x_2):
        if(self.measure == "euklid"):
            self.dist = euklid_distance(x_1,x_2)
        elif(self.measure == "abs"):
            self.dist = abs_distance(x_1,x_2)

dist1 = ExampleDist(measure = "euklid")
dist1.dist(np.array([1,1]),np.array([0,2]))
```

However in the K-Mean Algorithm I would have to copy-paste the whole loop where the distances between the datapoints and centroid is calculated and only change the distances.

Copy pasting is never a good solution, so I would hope to have a solution that automatically passes on which distance measure I want to use.
Like so (pseudo code):

```
class ExampleDist():
    def __init__(self, measure="euklid"):
        self.measure = measure
    
    def euklid_distance(x_1,x_2):
        dist = np.linalg.norm(x_1-x_2)
        return dist
    
    def abs_distance(x_1,x_2):
        dist = np.absolute(x_1-x_2)
        return dist
    
    def dist(self, x_1, x_2):
        self.dist = [self.meassure]_distance(x_1,x_2)

dist1 = ExampleDist(measure = "euklid")
dist1.dist(np.array([1,1]),np.array([0,2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a single `dist` function, like:

```
class ExampleDist():
    def __init__(self, measure="euklid"):
        self.measure = measure

    def dist(self, x_1, x_2):
        if self.measure == 'euklid':
            return np.linalg.norm(x_1-x_2)
        elif self.measure == 'absolute':
            return np.absolute(x_1-x_2)
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: I feel stupid ... but looks good thanks haha!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the distance functions you are going to have will accept the same arguments (`x1` and `x2`), you can use a dict to map between the distance type and the distance function.

This is one of the most expandable and flexible ways to achieve this.

```
class ExampleDist():
    _distance_funcs = {'euclid': np.linalg.norm,
                       'abs': np.absolute}  
                        # or implement your own wrappers as in your example

    def dist(self, x1, x2, measure):
        try:
            return self._distance_funcs[measure](x1, x2)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(f"`measure` should be one of {', '.join(self._distance_funcs.keys())}")
```